# show application is not working

Tags: gnome, kali-linux, menu

every time I click on ***show application*** my Kali crashes and goes to the main screen after a few minutes, the **application** extension (top left corner) that I downloaded afterward seems to be working fine, but I can't pull out the full menu grid directly from gnome, also I cannot search any application on the search bar....Any idea why and how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open gnome-tweak-tool (if you can't get to it from the gnome lens, use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gnome-tweaks`).
2. Under the "Extensions" tab, deselect extensions you think may contribute to this
3. Test that the issue has gone away
4. Re-enable extensions one-by-one until you have isolated the problem.

Comment: Aha...
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1071/applications-overview-tooltip/
this was the problem... I've disabled it...thank u for the help.